# joining two tables and fetching values from them error

Tags: php, html, css, php-5.3

i am joining the two tables but is giving me error that mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `photo_gallery`.`photographs` WHERE id=1");
$result .=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `photo_gallery`.`users` WHERE id=1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo 'You are Welcome'.'<br/>';
$Id=$row['id'];
$Name=$row['username'];
$Batch=$row['password'];
$Address=$row['first_name'];
$Course=$row['last_name'];
$filename=$row['filename'];
$type=$row['type'];
echo 'your ID is'.$Id.'<br/>'.'username '. $Name.'<br/>'.'your password '. $Batch.'<br/>'.'yor first name'. $Address. '<br/>'.'last'.$Course.'<br/>'.'file name is'.'<br/>'.$filename.'<br/>'.'type is '.$type;
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't concatenate the results of queries like that; if you really want to do that sort of thing, you can JOIN the tables, or use UNION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the most easy syntax to use join function

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `databasename`.`firstablename` JOIN `seconddatabasename` ON firsttablename.id = secondtablename.id ");
```

If you want to work with join array than visit this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_join.asp.
I hope you get what join function is used for.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot chain mysql queries in php that way. you have 2 options.

create a real mysql join.

you can use the shorthand syntax:

`` SELECT * FROM `photographs` p, `users` u WHERE p.id = u.id AND id=1 ``

or a real join:

`` SELECT * FROM `photographs` p INNER JOIN `users` u WHERE p.id = u.id AND id=1 ``

might i suggest reading more about mysql joins:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: i have done right now in this i apperciate your efforts for me. my way that i have done this is : $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `photo_gallery`.`users` JOIN `photographs` ON users.id =  photographs.id ");

Comment: the most important part of joins is the "on" part. if you fail to add that mysql will try to join every row of one table to every row of the other. this problem increases exponentially if your joining more than 2 tables. and if your table data is huge this will take a very long time, and can potentially overflow mysql's memory, not to mention it will still not give you the results you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM photographs INNER JOIN users ON photographs.id = users.id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: No prob, glad to help. please upvote or accept answer if you found the answer helpful. And please feel free to ask anymore questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for cometment bro i will ask more and more but the people degrade me here

Comment: They get nicer the longer you stay, so don't worry about it.